# Gradle get version of the subproject

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

So I am working on a big gradle project with many subprojects...

Now, in the main build script `subprojects` section, i want to get the version of every specific subproject...
When in this section i try doing `project.name` i get the name of the subproject accordingly, all nice.

But when i do `project.version` then the root projects's version is returned... Not the one of the subproject...

Am i doing something wrong? Is it supposed to be so?

Comment: Could you please show how you refer to version and name (in code)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you do not have `gradle.properties` set for each of your subprojects, and you have it only at the root level.

Lets say I have a subproject named `sub_project`, I can have a `gradle.properties` inside the subproject with version info :

```
version=0.2.0
```

In absense of this, it will inherit the version defined at the root level.

```
subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'

    task getCurrentVersion << {
        println "$project.name"
        println "$project.version"
    }
}
```

Running the above task will correctly print the version and name.

`./gradlew :sub_project:getCurrentVersion`